# Back to basics: Assume good intentions and Be nice

Tags: discussion

There's a concept in the business world called "Back to basics"

When a company has drifted too far from it's principles, it often reviews itself, and starts a "back to basics" program/initiative.

What I always liked about TWP in particular, is the fact that the "be nice" policy along with the "assume good intentions" policy eliminated 90% of the problem.

If we go back to that, we will make life easier for everybody.

**Q:** Hey, I think this is a troll post!

**A:** Assume it's not. and answer it if it's on topic

There's a saying, if you look for trouble, you will find it.  Let's stop.

If someone is misbehaving, flag them, and leave it there.  Don't call people trolls, and don't go on troll hunts.  One reason that SE  **USED** to be hard to troll is that nobody reacted.

BTW, a favorite troll for many to pull off is to get a group so paranoid about trolling that they start a witch hunt over it.

We are adults here, and if we act as such, we, as the community can undo much of the damage that was done by SE.

so, in summation:

- BE NICE!  It costs nothing, but makes the place more enjoyable for everyone.
- ASSUME GOOD INTENTIONS!  we are a very VERY diverse community.  That means we all have to deal with the fact that others can come across as rude to us, often times without intending to do so.  I know I need to work on this one myself... (did I just hear Mr Positive chuckle at that one?)

Finally, if the CoC Armageddon does come, we will deal with it then.  Until then, Be happy.

Comment: Well, this is not one I thought would grab a close vote, or a down-vote.  hmmm

Comment: You're a downvote magnet my friend

Comment: @Kilisi yeah, it's amusing

Comment: Imho *if you look for trouble, you will find it*  is the essence of problems here. Well put

Comment: Very well said, If feel handling trolling and etc in this way is perfect it fits with the focus of the site.
If we want to be a great storage of information, we should focus on that, rather than winning a battle in the comments.

Comment: I'm a little confused - is this a statement from Stack Exchange or a personal plea to the community? (I don't view it as a bad thing, I'm just asking)

Comment: @MarkC. It can't be a statement from SE, so probably the latter.

Comment: @MarkC. It was just my vain attempt to try to restore peace, but SE seems to think that the best action to take once hitting rock bottom is to bring out the heavy equipment, and begin excavating

Comment: @RichardU It's sad to see, really.

Comment: @MarkC sad indeed.  I cannot believe the incredibly poor judgement on SE's part